# date_trunc value in Unix second , CrateDB

Tags: npgsql, cratedb

Im trying to group a set of data using date_trunc. But after executing the data i got the  grouped data in Date format (DD/MM/YY). How to get it to second using query ?

Table Sensor

```
----------------------------------
| sensorid | reading | timestamp  |
----------------------------------
|   1      |  100    | 1612331498 |
-----------------------------------
|   2      |  100    | 1614752263 |
-----------------------------------
|   1      |  10     | 1614752263 |
-----------------------------------

> select date_trunc('day', v.timestamp) as day,sum(reading) from sensor 
> v(timestamp,sensorid) where sensorid=1 group by  (DAY);

Output is

day                      sum
03/02/2021 12:00:00 am   100
03/03/2021 12:00:00 am   10
 
Expected result
day             sum
1612331498      100
1614752263      10
```

im using Npgsql C# client and cratedb.

```
CREATE TABLE sensor (
    sensorid int,
    reading double,
    timestamp double

);
```

Comment: `date_trunc('day', v.timestamp)` will result in an error because `date_trunc()` only works with `timestamp` and `date` values - not with numbers. Your query can't return the output you have

Comment: query is working

Comment: Then your `timestamp` column doesn't contain what you show us or you are using a different query or you are not using PostgreSQL. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=36aa8f1f12e0303f0f77e5d726e09139   (the part `from sensor v(timestamp,sensorid)` also makes no sense)

Comment: Please edit your question and add the create table statement.